# Cleaning up MySQL query string data without altering source database?

Tags: mysql, string, formatting

So I have some fields in my MySQL database that are strings and I need to clean them up to be more readable in the query.

For example, I want this:

```
name | interests
----------------
 abc | a:2:{i:0;s:9:"Education";i:1;s:6:"Health";}
 xyz | a:3:{i:0;s:9:"Education";i:1;s:15:"Humanitarianism";i:2;s:33:"Sustainability and Climate Change";}
```

to look like this:

```
name | interests
----------------
 abc | "Education"; "Health";
 xyz | "Education"; "Humanitarianism"; "Sustainability and Climate Change";
```

without altering the source database.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This `a:2:{i:0;s:9:"Education";i:1;s:6:"Health";}` is a serialized array. Its done by PHP. So you are going to have to use PHP to unserialize it before you can mess with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RiggsFolly's suggestion is almost certainly better, but just for fun, here's a crude and incomplete solution, using a helper table in MySQL (a table (ints) of integers (i) [0-9])...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY
,attributes VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('xyz','a:3:{i:0;s:9:"Education";i:1;s:15:"Humanitarianism";i:2;s:33:"Sustainability and Climate Change";}');

SELECT x.id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x.attributes,'"',(i+1)*2),'"',-1) SEPARATOR ';')n FROM my_table x,ints GROUP BY x.id;
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | n                                                              |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| xyz | Education;Humanitarianism;Sustainability and Climate Change;;} |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a lot of searching before I found someone talking about REGEXP_REPLACE. It's not listed on any of my mySQL reference sites.

So, I just used

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(table.values, '[a-z]:[0-9]*[[:punct:]]', '') AS interests
```